# What are treatable foetal conditions during pregnancy?

Tags: genetics, teratology

What are different foetal conditions during pregnancy that could be treated with appropriate prenatal genetic testing?

I only know that pregnant women are encouraged to take certain supplements to make sure certain conditions won't develop in the foetus, and which are apparently also the case for deficiencies in human growth hormone, but I imagine there must be other specific cases that are treatable for specific conditions diagnosed to only a small number of cases?

Comment: this question seems like it would require a full book to respond to it.  there must be scores or even hundreds of such conditions.  Could you maybe be more specific and focused - break the question up?  dietary conditions?  genetic tests?

Answer (score 1):

Your question probably expresses a subtle confusion about the prenatal diagnostics and genetic testing.

So, genetic testing is one of the diagnostic methods in prenatal diagnostics (among with the other methods, see the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenatal_testing#Methods_of_prenatal_screening_and_diagnosis)) which is used to diagnose genetic disorders of the foetus, whereas the disorders that are diagnosed on this stage are mostly genetic anomalies with dramatic impact on the feotus development, for example chromosome aberrations (like Down or Turner Syndromes). Should these conditions be diagnosed, the woman is given a choice to interrupt the pregnancy prematurely.

Less dramatic conditions (like [sickle-cell disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sickle_cell_anemia)) can be diagnosed at this time too, but are not treated before the birth.

The genetic disorders that are amenable to the dietary or medical treatment (like phenylketonuria or congenital hypothyroidism) are usually diagnosed in the [newborn screening tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newborn_screening) (newborn heel prickle test), because these screening is more precise and less dangerous compared to the pre-born diagnostics.

Comment: So are there any prenatal diagnostics that can be treated during pregnancy?